# How to filtering using dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to asp.net mvc , I will appreciate your help.

I designed a dropdown list which retrieves a list of names from database, I want to filter once the dropdown list selected. 
my view:

```
<div>@Html.DropDownList("DropDownList", "Select")</div>
```

```csharp
public ActionResult Index(string DropDownList)
    if (DropDownList == "Unknown") {
       searchPerson = searchPerson.Where(o => o.Person.PersonStatusId == 1);
    }  
    if (DropDownList == "Brother") { //something selected
        searchPerson = searchPerson.Where(o => o.Person.PersonStatusId == 4);
    }
```

It does not give me an error when I run , but it does not do anything. I want the filter begins once you select one of the option in drop down list ..

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the call to the back end. It wont just fire unless you set up the ajax call.

Jquery

```
//This will fire when you select a value. Make sure that the select list has the same id as 
//the one you are listening to. For instance Here the Id im listening to is selectList.

$("#selectList").change(function(){

    $.get("@Url.Action("GetPeople")",{id : $(this).val()}, function(results){
         //do what you want with results
    })

})
```

Make another get method in your back end. Calling the index method would be more for getting a view rather than data.

C#

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPeople(int id)
{
    //returned as json
    return Json(searchPerson.Where(o => o.Person.PersonStatusId == id));
}
```

In your selectlist have the text be the same but have the value be what ever the corresponding PersonStatusId is. This way you aren't having to do those if statements.

I can explain this in more detail if you need me to.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would be more than happy to see more help, So do I have to build another method to get people back to the view. ok So The drop down list is populated but as you said it does not fire , so I have to add ajex code

Comment: The jquery code I provided will listen to your selectlist. When you select a new item it will fire the code inside of it. That code is a ajax call that will call upon a method called GetPeople in your controller. The method will then return a ActionResult to that ajax code in the front end. You can grab the data(it will be json) using the paremeter I have called results in the function. You can then do what ever you want with that json data.

Comment: I made some edit to my answer to make it more exact with what you need.